# Does JPA have a Batch Annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

We are encountering the issue where we are getting a massive amount of queries being executed to load up our application.  There are obvious places where the queries could be optimized to pull a bunch of records at once instead of one at a time.  However, the batch annotations I have found only appear to exist in the actual persistence implementation (Hibernate / EclipseLink).  Am I missing something?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

S

Comment: Does Hibernate have a batch annotation? I have not seen it yet.

Comment: No, you're not missing anything.